# How to interact with ActionDispath object from file upload?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have an upload form in rails. I'd like to do some pre-processing on the uploaded file before other logic takes over.

When I print out the entire `params` I see that my uploaded file's data in params as:

```
"logo"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fbf2964d7b0 @original_filename="huddle-house.JPG", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"merchant[logo]\"; filename=\"huddle-house.JPG\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/rl/t02q9t1j3m53ktcqx_dj6zmc0000gn/T/RackMultipart20111222-605-1q58pp5>>,
```

**How can I access the `tempfile` that's in that ActionDispatch?**

I've tried the following and none of these work:

```
params[:logo][:tempfile]
params[:logo].tempfile
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, assuming `params[:logo]` returns that `ActionDispatch` object, you could try this:

```
params[:logo].instance_variable_get(:@tempfile)
```